# Photo management software with cloud backups?

Tags: windows, photography

I'm after some photo management software which ideally will let me:

- Go through all of my photos in a single view and quickly/easily and delete lots of them
- Remove duplicates
- Cloud sync so they’re backed up, and I can view them on my phone
- Use location metadata so I can browse photos on a map like iOS Photos
- Face recognition (bonus for pets!)

Any recommendations for software please? If I was on OSX I'd use Apple Photos, but unfortunately I'm on Windows 10. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Fotos](http://photos.google.com/) is what you want. Has even face recognition now.